# HiQPdf Evaluation tag added when printing

Tags: printing, hiqpdf

I have a c# dll that uses HiQPdf to print a PDF from file. The issue is the printed PDF has a string added to the top left saying "HiQPdf Evaluation". The marigins are also greatly increased making the image smaller.

When I open the pdf and print from there it is fine. I couldn't find anything on the string being added so hoping someone here might have some insight :)

code:

```
    public void PrintFromFile(string fileName, System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings printerSettings)
    {
        var imagePrinter = new PdfPrinter();
        imagePrinter.PrinterSettings.Copies = printerSettings.Copies;
        imagePrinter.PrinterSettings.Duplex = printerSettings.Duplex;
        imagePrinter.PrinterSettings.FromPage = printerSettings.FromPage;
        imagePrinter.PrinterSettings.MaximumPage = printerSettings.MaximumPage;
        imagePrinter.PrinterSettings.MinimumPage = printerSettings.MinimumPage;
        imagePrinter.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerSettings.PrinterName;
        imagePrinter.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = printerSettings.PrintFileName;
        imagePrinter.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = printerSettings.PrintRange;
        imagePrinter.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = printerSettings.PrintToFile;
        imagePrinter.PrinterSettings.ToPage = printerSettings.ToPage;
        imagePrinter.PrinterSettings.Collate = printerSettings.Collate;

        var pdf = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("V:\\AccW2\\" + fileName));
        pdf.Position = 0;
        imagePrinter.PrintPdf(pdf);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an HtmlToPdf element in you PrintPdf function you should set your SerialNumber

```
    private void PrintPdf(string htmlbody, string pdfname)
{
    HtmlToPdf htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf();
    // set a demo serial number
    htmlToPdfConverter.SerialNumber = "-- HiQPdf Serial Number --";

}
```